# having trouble grouping information SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, grouping

I am having trouble grouping some information from two tables to compare information.

I have two tables

```
Baseline
|ResourceGroup    Unit     TotalUnits|
|Mechanic           50            600|
|Electric           50            600|
|Mechanic           52            600|
|Electric           52            600|    

Actual
|ResourceGroup    Unit     TotalUnits|
|Mechanic           50            500|
|Electric           50            500|
|Mechanic           52            500|
|Electric           52            500|
```

What I would like to see is the following:

```
|ResourceGroup    Baseline.TotalUnits  Actual.TotalUnits|
|Mechanic                    1200                   1000|
|Electric                    1200                   1000|
```

I am trying to use the following query, but it doesn't seem to work. I think I am missing something. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
SELECT Baseline.ResourceGroup, Baseline.TotalUnits, Actual.TotalUnits 
INNER JOIN Baseline.ResourceGroup = Actual.ResourceGroup
GROUP BY ResourceGroup;
```

Comment: Just at a glance, you're missing a `FROM` clause

Comment: This is not a well formed query. Try formatting it this way `Select columnName1, columnName2,.. FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.columnNameN1 = Table2.columnNameN2 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-joining of these two tables would give you 2x2=4 rows per ResourceGroup meaning you will have 4 rows of Mechanic and 4 rows of Electric data. And grouping after you already have joined them will give you mismatching values.

Solution is to group those tables separately and after join the resulted tables. This would give you following two tables that you need to join by ResourceGroup column:

```
Baseline
|ResourceGroup    TotalUnits|
|Mechanic           1200|
|Electric           1200|

Actual
|ResourceGroup     TotalUnits|
|Mechanic           1000|
|Electric           1000|
```

Figure out following sql statement:

```
SELECT
    A.ResourceGroup,
    A.TotalUnits as BaselineTotalUnits,
    B.TotalUnits as ActualTotalUnits
FROM (SELECT ResourceGroup, SUM(TotalUnits) as TotalUnits FROM Baseline GROUP BY ResourceGroup) A
JOIN (SELECT ResourceGroup, SUM(TotalUnits) as TotalUnits FROM Actual GROUP BY ResourceGroup) B
    ON A.ResourceGroup = B.ResourceGroup
```

Comment: Although your answer gives the right result, you don't really need subqueries to get what the OP needs; it's enough to join both tables and perform the aggregation on each column

Comment: Can you please give an example of statement? I really do not get how you can achieve that without doing grouping first... Thank you! :)

Comment: You're right! After reading again the data sample in the OP, I see what you mean. I'm sorry for the inconvenience (deleting my previous answer now)

Comment: @Barranka thank you very much for your help. I grabbed that link before you deleted the post.

Comment: @GSazheniuk Thank you for the explaination, I can see after reviewing your query that I need quite a bit of work on understanding how to setup queries.

Comment: @JohnFayt you are welcome. Just keep in mind, each time you need to use aggregates over joined data check whether rows from any table are multiplied or not. If answer is Yes it means you will probably get wrong aggregated data on those rows, of course unless you use only Min() or Max() aggregates. :)